# When an rc version is available, which python version is supposed to use, 3.6.1 or 3.6.2rc?

Tags: python

I know 3.6.2 is already released, and in most cases it makes few differences. **I'm just curious**, in the stage that 3.6.2rc has just released, should I use 3.6.1 or 3.6.2rc if I want the **latest stable** version?

In other words, which one is supposed to be more stable, i.e., has less bugs?

Comment: If stable, *don't* use a release candidate. Thus, use 3.6.1.

Comment: As to "more stable": both are bugfix releases in the first place: the API will be stable along the whole of the 3.6 series. It really depends on your purpose.

Comment: @Evert Since both are bigfix releases, which one is supposed to have less bugs?

Comment: Normally the later version; this should be obvious. There is always a minimal chance a bugfix inserts a new bug, but that is really rare (and in such a case, you'd still have 10 or more bugfixes versus 1 new bug).

Comment: Your question may make more sense if you tell us the actual problem you're facing and are trying to solve.

Comment: @Evert According to the supposed number of bugs, it seems the RC versions are preffered. I'm curious about what's the purpose of an RC version of a bugfix release. I admit this problem may be meaningless in pratical. Since in most cases, since both version should work great.

Comment: If RC were preferred, then full releases would never be made

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean rc with hither version number is preffered over releasing version with lower version number, i.e., 3.6.2 > 3.6.2rc > 3.6.1.

Comment: RC is (to my knowledge) mainly about deployment testing. Continuous integration will already take of this partially, but it gives other people a chance to download the release candidate and deploy it on a testing machine, to see that nothing breaks for them (e.g., they're code may actual rely on buggy behaviour). If no-one finds problems, the final version will be exactly the same as the release candidate version.

Comment: All in all: use the current release, and wait (a few weeks, a few months) for the next release. Don't fret it: it is *extremely* unlikely you have code that relies on bug-fixes in the current release candidate.

Comment: Umm, that's how semantic versions  work. There was likely a 3.6.1rcX at some point

Comment: By the way http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.6.1. "RC" indicates a release candidate--something that is still officially along the lines of a beta, and not something that should be used for a production system. It still has to go through final testing before being declared the stable version.

Comment: 3.6.*2* RC, not 3.6.1.